# Workflow - Can not select right rows

Tags: workflow

I have created this workflow by copying a workflow(macro) I recorded from our company system in the hope to relieve me from heavy data entry work. However, when I play the workflow, it failed to select the right row on a list(grid). Instead, it always selects the first row no matter what row I designate. I don't know which programming language the system uses. It was saved using the `.P` extension. Here is a part that caused the problem. The third last sentence (`SELECT_ROW("2")`) was not properly executed.

```
SELECT_TAB("po-proc-tabpage-1").

SET_FIELD("scr-po-num","02.6430").

SELECT_TAB("NONE").

CHOOSE_BUTTON("button-edit").

CHOOSE_BUTTON("button-items").
GET_DIALOG("poitment.p","poitment-004").

SELECT_GRID("br-item").

RESET_GRID_SORT().

SELECT_ROW("2").

CHOOSE_BUTTON("badd-charges").
GET_DIALOG("poitmchg.p","poitmchg-004").
```

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I think you'd get a better answer on [su]. Although this is a programming question, it also involves productivity software.